# Apache Commons Email base64 Imagem

Tags: java, apache, email, base64

Possuo um software para enviar emails que utilizar apache commons email para enviar emails html, possuo no banco de dados tambem uma string que representa uma imagem base64 exemplo `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K ....`

tentei utilizar a tag img de html para enviar esse email mas nao adiantou, achei alguns tutoriais que ensinam usando uma imagem da internet como esse por exemplo.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html

gostaria de saber se alguem pode me ajudar a converter essa string em imagem, anexao no email e usa-la no corpo do email usando a api apache commons email

Metodo para enviar o email esta da seguinte forma

```
public String enviarEmail(Email mail) throws Exception {
        try {
                HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
                email.setCharset(EmailConstants.UTF_8);
                email.setHostName("myHost");
                email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
                email.setSmtpPort(99);
                String[] destinatarios =(String[])mail.getLstDestinatarios().toArray(new String[0]);
                email.addBcc(destinatarios);
                email.setFrom(mail.getRemetente());                 
                email.setSubject(mail.getAssunto());
                email.setHtmlMsg(mail.getMensagem());
                email.send();
                return "email enviado com sucesso";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new WebApplicationException(e);
        }
```

Comment: Como está a classe que manda e-mail ?

Comment: Resposta nesse link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979842/convert-base64-string-to-image

Comment: Você transforma seu Array base64 em image igual no link como no comment acima.
A anexa usando EmailAttachment();